# Modify default saving folder/location for Adobe CS6 (Ps, Ai, Id) in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, photoshop-cs6, file-location, save-as, adobe-cs6

**In Adobe Photoshop CS6:**

Selecting `Menubar / Save As…` (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) defaults to the file's current folder (*expected*).

Selecting `Menubar / Save for Web…` (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) defaults to the `~/Documents` folder (*unexpected*). This behavior is confusing; the file's current folder is expected.

---

**In Adobe Illustrator CS6:**

Selecting `Menubar / Save As…` (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) defaults to the open file's current folder (*expected*).

Selecting `Menubar / Export…` (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) defaults to the open file's current folder (*expected*).

Selecting `Menubar / Save for Web…` (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) defaults to the `~/Desktop` folder (*unexpected*). This behavior is annoying (better than `~/Documents` at least); the file's current folder is expected.

---

**In Adobe InDesign CS6:**

Selecting `Menubar / Save As…` (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) defaults to the *application's* last saved-to folder (*unexpected*). This is the worst outcome; it frequently results in misplaced items. The *file's* current (last saved-to) folder is expected.

Selecting `Menubar / Export…` (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) defaults to the *application's* last save folder (*unexpected*). This is the worst outcome; it frequently results in misplaced items. The *file's* current (last saved-to) folder is expected.

---

I've looked through each application's preferences. Might there be something I missed, or some hack to correct this?

Thank you.

Comment: not an answer, but I've always used DefaultFolder to get around where things want to be saved - http://www.stclairsoft.com - an imperfect solution, but one I've lived with for 10 years.